# Mysql query to calculate total cost

Tags: mysql

HI
I have a table listsing_prices (id,listing_id,day_from,day_to,price)
I need to calculate the total cost of an holiday in mysql becouse I need to sort the results by total cost.

EX:

```
VALUES IN TABLE
1  6   2011-04-27   2011-04-30   55,00
2  6   2011-05-01   2011-05-02   60,00
3  6   2011-05-03   2011-05-15   65,00
```

holiday from 2011-04-28 to 2011-05-05 total cost = 480

Comment: if the holidays were not adjacent (like `04-27` to `04-29`), do you want one record or two in the resultset?

Comment: With those values, how do you get the total cost to be 480?

Comment: I get 480 like:
day 28/4 55
day 29/4 55
day 30/4 55
day 01/5 60
day 02/5 60
day 03/5 65
day 04/5 65
day 05/5 65

TOTAL 480

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without creating an actual table to represent every day from start date to end date, you could use mysql query variables.  The first query can join to any table as long as it has as many records as days you are concerned with for the hoiday period... in this case, 8 days from April 28 to May 5.  By doing a Cartesian and limiting to 8 will in essence, create a temp result set with one record per each day, starting with 2011/04/28 (your starting date).

Then, this is joined back to your pricing table that matches the date period and sums the matching price for total costs...

```
select  
        sum( pt.price ) as TotalCosts
    from 
        ( SELECT 
                 @r:= date_add(@r, interval 1 day ) CalendarDate
            FROM 
                 (select @r := STR_TO_DATE('2011/04/28', '%Y/%m/%d')) vars,
                AnyTableWithAtLeast8ays limit 8 ) JustDates,
        PricesTable pt
    where
        JustDates.CalendarDate between pt.date_from and pt.date_to
```

Comment: what you mean with AnyTableWithAtLeast8ays

Comment: @Igor, i guess you figured it out... it could be ANY table you have, but it has to have as many days as you expect to be computing costs forward with... if you wanted cost for 30 days, just ensure whatever table is referenced has that many records...  Its just to force a Cartesian result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(price) from listing_prices where day_from >= '2011-04-28' and day_to <= '2011-05-05'
```

Comment: `count`? I think you mean `sum`? But even that will not give the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah, the use of COUNT nor SUM make sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- This will provide a list of ids along with how many days fall between the two
SELECT a.id, DATEDIFF(DAYS, CASE WHEN day_from < '2011-04-28' THEN '2011-04-28' ELSE day_from END CASE, day_to) AS DayCount
FROM listing_prices a
WHERE '2011-04-28' BETWEEN a.date_from AND a.date_to
    AND a.date_to <= '2011-05-05'

-- Based on the previous query, sum the number of days within the range
SELECT SUM( a.price * b.DayCount ) AS Total
FROM listing_prices a
JOIN ( SELECT a.id, DATEDIFF(DAYS, CASE WHEN day_from < '2011-04-28' THEN '2011-04-28' ELSE day_from END CASE, day_to) AS DayCount
FROM listing_prices a
WHERE '2011-04-28' BETWEEN a.date_from AND a.date_to
    AND a.date_to <= '2011-05-05'
```

) b ON a.id = b.id

Please note that this is untested ... the query at the top I believe should work but if it doesn't, it can be modified and so that it does work (get the number of days within each range) and then literally copied and pasted into the subquery of the second query.  The second query is the one that you will actually use.